# Error while labelling data for Visual Recognition box detection in Watson Studio

Tags: watson-studio

I am using Watson Studio to build a Visual Recognition model for detecting farms in satellite images by using Object detection.

When I try to add labels (with add objects) to the pictures I have uploaded to the model the following error occurs:

> An error occurred while updating farm_vb_1.png
>   Error in Watson Visual Recognition service: Received empty image data response.

My question is why I get this message and how I can fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?